# Azure Mobile Services on IISExpress gives me the error - web server is not configured to list the contents of this directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

After update for the latest AzureMobile.Services.Backend.Tables package, when i try to run my application at IISExpress or LocalIIS appears this error:

**Web server is not configured to list the contents of this directory.**

Im aware that azure mobile service which is an asp.net web api does not have an home page which is generate on runtime.I tried to create a new azure mobile services and it works fine as well.

Am I missing something on my webconfig?

Comment: you get this error when you attempt to access your api routes or just when you try to access the root of the server?

Comment: I get this error when i run the project from visual studio.

Comment: yes, but what URL are you trying to browse to when the error occurs in your browser?

Comment: http://localhost:13188/

Comment: right, so do you have an index.html or something to respond with? it sounds there isn't one... so does browsing to an API method, e.g. `http://localhost:13188/api/someAPIMethod` return the data it should?

Comment: No.Nothing of that work.Every url from http://localhost:13188/ returns the error 404.And if the home page(that blue screen that are generated from azure mobile services) is not shown.The error -> web server is not configured to list the contents of this directory is shown instead.

Comment: are you sure that the random port number generated by IIS Express didn't change? i.e. your URL might not be http://localhost:13188/ anymore?

Comment: Im sure because i did try to change the port in IISExpress and run in the local IIS and i get the same result.

Comment: Even after reinstalling visual studio and azure tools the error persists.Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating another project of Mobile Services with an default template.